# Maxima: Module ezunits needs compilation every time

Tags: maxima

I have been using fake units in Maxima until today, when I realized there were unit packages which supported conversions and other cool features. I have found ezunits to be the most complete package of its family, however I have found a problem with it.

Every time I want to use it, I have to compile it. In other words, running the line `load(ezunits)` starts a compilation process and spits as output the location of the `ezunits.mac` file. However, if one was to open a new maxima session and ran `load(ezunits)` on it, the compilation would be executed again. One would expect to have to compile once only and just load a compiled file ever after.

Is there a way I can work this around?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to suppress all the messages about compilation. You can edit your copy of ezunits_functions.mac and comment out the line that begins `compile (constantp_not0, ...)` or just delete it.

Another way to go about this is to compile and load ezunits into Maxima, then save the current image (now containing default Maxima plus ezunits). Then you can load that updated image instead of the default and ezunits will be present already.

I am guessing that you are working on Windows and Maxima is compiled with GCL. I don't know for sure how to dump an image in that case. For GCL on Linux it is: `(si:save-system "myimagename")` You would also need to modify the Maxima batch script to load your updated image.

By the way, I wrote the ezunits package so if you have any questions or comments, I would be interested to hear about it.

Comment: Oh, what an honor! I will try your proposal and report back if I have success. I wonder though, what are the benefits from having it compile on startup every time?

Comment: Well, it runs a little faster if it is compiled. Also, it is a test for the compiler -- that is a concern for me, because I am a developer, but not for you, as a user.

Comment: Ok I commented out the line you suggested in the solution, but maxima still compiles `ezunits` when I run `load(ezunits)`, perhaps there is another hook somewhere? Also, I am using Linux but the command to dump the image returned `incorrect syntax: myimagename is not an infix operator`

Comment: Hm performing the same "outcomment" in the file `ezunits.mac` seemed to work just fine, I will report any further problems, thanks!

Comment: How do I decide whether to use "ezunits" or "unit"?  You appear to have worked on both.  Why isn't there just a single package for this?  Why backticks instead of normal multiplication signs?

Comment: @endolith, I'll try to answer your questions. There are multiple packages because there have been many Maxima developers and different people have come up with different solutions to the same problems. That is just part of the Maxima developer culture, which has been going on now for 40+ years. ezunits uses backticks because Maxima will reorder multiplicative expressions. I wanted to make sure that something like `a * z meters` didn't turn into `a * meters * z` (i.e. keep all units at end).